# Can PowerShell dot notation be used on multiple lines?

Tags: powershell

To make scripts more readable I would like to break things up on multiple lines.  Is this possible in PowerShell's dot notation?

For example, take this:

```
(GC myfile.txt).Replace('a',b').Replace('c','d').Replace('e','f') | SC newfile.txt
```

And write it like this:

```
(GC myfile.txt).Replace('a',b')
    .Replace('c','d')
    .Replace('e','f') |
    SC newfile.txt
```

I have tried using backticks (`) and they don't work.  Are there any options?  I guess assume PowerShell v3+

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the same issue, the easiest way to solve it is to place the point before breaking the line

```
(GC myfile.txt).Replace('a',b').
    Replace('c','d')
```

Comment: Learned something new today.  Thanks!